# Passing arguments to a convenience method on one class that calls method from another

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a prototype method like so:

```
ProjectClient.prototype = {
    connect: function() {
        console.log('ARGS: ' + Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        // this bit takes a data object, a relationship string, and another data object as arguments, 
        // e.g. client.connect(user1, 'likes', user2):
        var options = helpers.build.connection(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))
        request({
            uri: options.uri,
            method: 'POST',
            json: true
        }, function(error, response) {
            var customResponse = new CustomResponse(response)
            options.callback(error, customResponse)
        })
    }
}
```

This relies on an instance of `ProjectClient` being passed to the `helpers.build.connection` method. I've also got a 'singleton' shared instance of `ProjectClient` that is in use. For convenience, I'm adding a copy of this `connect()` method to `ProjectEntity` like so:

```
ProjectEntity.prototype = {
    connect: function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        args.unshift(this)
        return Project.connect(args)
    }
}
```

It's not working properly though -- this gets me a nested array of arguments when doing `console.log('ARGS: ' + Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`:

```
 ARGS: [ [ arg1, arg2, arg3 ] ]
```

Where I'd expect:

```
 ARGS: [ arg1, arg2, arg3 ]
```

What's a more consistent way of passing arguments to `ProjectClient.prototype.connect()` so that I can get what I'm expecting? I tried using `Project.connect.apply(args)` too, but since I'm returning the function (not actually calling it here) `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` ends up an empty array. If there is no better way of doing this, what's the best workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `.apply()` like this to pass an arbitrary set of arguments to a function:

```
ProjectEntity.prototype = {
    connect: function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        args.unshift(this);
        return Project.connect.apply(Project, args);
    }
}
```

`.apply()` takes two arguments itself.  The first is whatever you want the `this` argument to be inside the function you are calling.  The second is an array of arguments that you want to be passed to the function as individual arguments (not passed as the array itself).

More documentation on `.apply()` [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: Doh! I was missing `Project` as the first argument when I tried using `apply`. Thanks!

Comment: @remus - If this answered your question, then please finish things off by marking an accepted answer.

Comment: Oh weird... I accepted it in the mobile app. Maybe it was goofed.